# PGAgent : Caught unhandled unknown exception; terminating

Tags: pgagent

The trouble with constantly running jobs on postgre DB, which will never finished.

I have tried the following actions to fix it:

- apt-get update & upgrade(postgresql was updated to latest)
- /etc/init.d/postgresql restart

  ```
  postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Fri 2015-10-16 10:06:04 UTC; 9s ago
     Process: 6787 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Main PID: 6787 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
       CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service
  ```
- /etc/init.d/pgagent restart

  ```
  pgagent.service - Postgres Job Agent Daemon
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/pgagent.service; enabled)
    Active: active (running) since Fri 2015-10-16 10:06:04 UTC; 1min 48s ago
    Main PID: 6793 (pgagent)
       CGroup: /system.slice/pgagent.service
         └─6793 /usr/bin/pgagent -f -l 2 -s /var/log/pgagent hostaddr=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgresext

  Oct 16 10:07:00 m-t-db-01 pgagent[6793]: *** Caught unhandled unknown exception; terminating
  Oct 16 10:07:50 m-t-db-01 pgagent[6793]: *** Caught unhandled unknown exception; terminating
  ```
- tried to enable debug mode on pgagent `vim /etc/default/pgagent`

  ```
  EXTRA_OPTS="-f -l 2 -s /var/log/pgagent hostaddr=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgresext"
  ```
- tried to reboot the machine
- in `/var/log/pgagent` log I see only:

  ```
  ERROR: Failed to query jobs table!
  DEBUG: Creating primary connection
  DEBUG: Connection Information:
  DEBUG:      user         : postgresext
  DEBUG:      port         : 0
  DEBUG:      host         : localhost
  DEBUG:      dbname       : postgres
  DEBUG:      password     :
  DEBUG:      conn timeout : 0
  DEBUG: Connection Information:
  DEBUG:      user         : postgresext
  DEBUG:      port         : 0
  DEBUG:      host         : localhost
  DEBUG:      dbname       : postgres
  DEBUG:      password     :
  DEBUG:      conn timeout : 0
  DEBUG: Creating DB connection: user=postgresext host=localhost dbname=postgres
  DEBUG: Database sanity check
  DEBUG: Clearing zombies
  DEBUG: Checking for jobs to run
  DEBUG: Sleeping...
  DEBUG: Clearing inactive connections
  DEBUG: Connection stats: total - 1, free - 0, deleted - 0
  DEBUG: Checking for jobs to run
  DEBUG: Sleeping...
  DEBUG: Creating primary connection
  DEBUG: Connection Information:
  DEBUG:      user         : postgresext
  DEBUG:      port         : 0
  DEBUG:      host         : localhost
  DEBUG:      dbname       : postgres
  DEBUG:      password     :
  DEBUG:      conn timeout : 0
  DEBUG: Connection Information:
  DEBUG:      user         : postgresext
  DEBUG:      port         : 0
  DEBUG:      host         : localhost
  DEBUG:      dbname       : postgres
  DEBUG:      password     :
  DEBUG:      conn timeout : 0
  DEBUG: Creating DB connection: user=postgresext host=localhost dbname=postgres
  DEBUG: Database sanity check
  DEBUG: Clearing zombies
  DEBUG: Checking for jobs to run
  DEBUG: Sleeping...
  DEBUG: Clearing inactive connections
  DEBUG: Connection stats: total - 1, free - 0, deleted - 0
  DEBUG: Checking for jobs to run
  DEBUG: Sleeping...
  DEBUG: Clearing inactive connections
  DEBUG: Connection stats: total - 1, free - 0, deleted - 0
  DEBUG: Checking for jobs to run
  DEBUG: Creating job thread for job 8
  DEBUG: Creating DB connection: user=postgresext host=localhost dbname=postgres
  DEBUG: Allocating new connection to database postgres
  DEBUG: Starting job: 8
  DEBUG: Creating job thread for job 5
  DEBUG: Creating DB connection: user=postgresext host=localhost dbname=postgres
  DEBUG: Allocating new connection to database postgres
  DEBUG: Starting job: 5
  DEBUG: Creating DB connection: user=postgresext host=localhost dbname=postgres dbname=testdb
  DEBUG: Sleeping...
  DEBUG: Allocating new connection to database testdb
  DEBUG: Executing SQL step 23 (part of job 8)
  DEBUG: Creating DB connection: user=postgresext host=localhost dbname=postgres dbname=testdb
  DEBUG: Allocating new connection to database testdb
  DEBUG: Executing SQL step 15 (part of job 5)
  DEBUG: Checking for jobs to run
  DEBUG: Sleeping...
  DEBUG: Clearing inactive connections
  DEBUG: Connection stats: total - 5, free - 0, deleted - 0
  DEBUG: Checking for jobs to run
  DEBUG: Sleeping...
  DEBUG: Destroying job thread for job 8
  DEBUG: Clearing inactive connections
  DEBUG: Connection stats: total - 5, free - 0, deleted - 0
  DEBUG: Checking for jobs to run
  DEBUG: Sleeping...
  DEBUG: Clearing inactive connections
  DEBUG: Connection stats: total - 5, free - 0, deleted - 0
  DEBUG: Checking for jobs to run
  DEBUG: Sleeping...
  DEBUG: Clearing inactive connections
  DEBUG: Connection stats: total - 5, free - 0, deleted - 0
  DEBUG: Checking for jobs to run
  DEBUG: Sleeping...
  DEBUG: Clearing inactive connections
  DEBUG: Connection stats: total - 5, free - 0, deleted - 0
  DEBUG: Checking for jobs to run
  DEBUG: Sleeping...
  ```
- in `vim /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log` I see only:

  ```
  [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
  LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
  LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
  LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
  postgresext@postgres LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
  postgresext@testdb LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
  postgresext@postgres LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
  postgresext@postgres LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
  postgresext@testdb LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
  postgresext@postgres LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
  postgresext@postgres LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
  postgresext@testdb LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
  postgresext@testdb LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
  postgresext@testdb LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
  postgresext@postgres LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
  ```

I cannot figure out what the actual problem and how to fix it actually?

One more thing I have investigated is that `pgagent[6793]: *** Caught unhandled unknown exception; terminating` can be invoked by incorrect connection termination...

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late to answering this, but I ran into the same issues when using pgAgent, and it caused nothing but frustration. I even tried to dig into the source to fix it, but just trying to get it to compile on my server was a total nightmare due to the dependencies it requires (for no good reason).

So with that in mind, I decided to write a new job scheduler for Postgres as a drop in replacement for pgAgent.  It's called [jpgAgent](https://github.com/Tostino/jpgAgent), and i've been using it at my company for a couple months now with no issues at all.  Much more stable now that we're using jpgAgent, don't have to worry about the agent just stopping on us randomly and jobs not getting run as they should, where as previously that was a common problem.

Anyways, hope it helps you out.